# Add new line into the Excel Table if Condition meet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel Table in which I'd like to add new line if condition meet. Actually my code is working partly. It adds lines but when the work finish Debug appears (Run-time error 13, type mismatch).
I am in trouble if sometimes unexpected error happens. So please help me make my code more advance and work properly.

```
Sub AddWorkingYearLine2()

    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("DB")
        For i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 4 Step -1
            'make sure it's not an "old entry"
            If Cells(i, "A").Value2 <> Cells(i + 1, "A").Value2 Then
                'if today occurs after "end date" then
                If Range("D1") > CDate(Cells(i, "F").Value) And Len(Cells(i, "F").Value2) > 0 Then
                    'insert row
                    Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown

                    'copy row down
                    'Rows(i + 1).Value = Rows(i).Value

                    'update dates
                    Cells(i + 1, "A").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value
                    Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = Cells(i, "B").Value
                    Cells(i + 1, "C").Value = Cells(i, "C").Value
                    Cells(i + 1, "D").Value = Cells(i, "D").Value
                    Cells(i + 1, "E").Value = Cells(i, "F").Value
                    Cells(i + 1, "F").Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, CDate(Cells(i + 1, "E").Value))
                    Cells(i + 1, "G").Value = Cells(i, "M").Value
                    Cells(i + 1, "H").Value = Cells(i, "H").Value
                    Cells(i + 1, "I").Value = Cells(i, "I").Value
                    Cells(i + 1, "J").Value = Cells(i, "J").Value

                    Application.CutCopyMode = False

                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using `With Worksheets("DB")` but then you're not referencing all range objects to `Worksheets("DB")` object since you're not using dots...

```
Dim i As Long

With Worksheets("DB")
    For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 4 Step -1
        'make sure it's not an "old entry"
        If .Cells(i, "A").Value2 <> .Cells(i + 1, "A").Value2 Then
            'if today occurs after "end date" then
            If .Range("D1") > CDate(.Cells(i, "F").Value) And Len(.Cells(i, "F").Value2) > 0 Then
                'insert row
                .Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown

                'copy row down
                'Rows(i + 1).Value = Rows(i).Value

                'update dates
                .Cells(i + 1, "A").Value = .Cells(i, "A").Value
                .Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = .Cells(i, "B").Value
                .Cells(i + 1, "C").Value = .Cells(i, "C").Value
                .Cells(i + 1, "D").Value = .Cells(i, "D").Value
                .Cells(i + 1, "E").Value = .Cells(i, "F").Value
                .Cells(i + 1, "F").Value = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, CDate(.Cells(i + 1, "E").Value))
                .Cells(i + 1, "G").Value = .Cells(i, "M").Value
                .Cells(i + 1, "H").Value = .Cells(i, "H").Value
                .Cells(i + 1, "I").Value = .Cells(i, "I").Value
                .Cells(i + 1, "J").Value = .Cells(i, "J").Value

                Application.CutCopyMode = False

            End If
        End If
    Next

End With
```

Comment: thanks for your corrections. But still I get same debug, and error highlight this part.
`If .Range("D1") > CDate(.Cells(i, "F").Value) And Len(.Cells(i, "F").Value2) > 0 Then`

Comment: what are the values of `.Range("D1")`, `.Cells(i, "F").Value` and `.Cells(i, "F").Value2` upon hitting the error?

Comment: `.Range("D1")` contains today formula.
`.Cells(i, "F").value` shows dates for transaction.
`.Cells(i, "F").value2` also relate to dates.

Comment: `If .Range("D1") > Range("F" & i).Value And Len(.Cells(i, "F").Value2) > 0 Then` I changed previous into this one. Now it works properly. I really appreciate your help @DisplayName. Just one more question. What do you think this code is enough good for handle 1000 or 2000 rows of data and check the all lines properly?

Comment: As for speed issue, accessing worksheet cells is always slowing down things, and you should make a test to see if it's sufficient for your purposes . A faster way is dumping data in and writing them back out of arrays. Finally, marking answer as accepted is an appreciated way to show real appreciation. Thank you